# Using mu-plugins on the Genesis Framework

Tags: plugins, genesis-theme-framework, mu-plugins

So this is how I have my structure setup to attempt to create a mu-plugin for my page.

Here is what I'm using:
- Genesis Framework
- Genesis FrameWork Child Theme

Please let me know if the mu-plugins directory should be there or moved inside the child theme, also to create just a simple mu plugin that echos 'Hello', where would I begin? Learning as I'm doing this.

Here is my current structure:
[image: u]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `mu-plugins`? `mu-plugins` and the genesis framework are unrelated, one is a parent theme, the other is a part of core WordPress. It doesn't make much sense to say you want create a plugin for a page, can you provide more context? Also, 3rd party theme support is offtopic on WPSE, you should contact Genesis support for Genesis support, or Genesis communities

Answer (score 0):

> So this is how I have my structure setup to attempt to create a mu-plugin for my page.

This statement does not make sense.

> Here is what I'm using: - Genesis Framework - Genesis FrameWork Child Theme

`mu-plugins` have nothing to do with the Genesis framework. The Genesis framework is just a parent theme like any other WP theme. It was just built with the intention that you would build a child theme.

> Please let me know if the mu-plugins directory should be there or moved inside the child theme,

You should never move the `mu-plugins` folder

> also to create just a simple mu plugin that echos 'Hello', where would I begin? Learning as I'm doing this.

To say there's such a thing as an *mu plugin* is a bit of a stretch, but, this would be the equivalent:

```php
<?php
echo "Hello";
exit;
```

The above code, saved in `wp-content/mu-plugins/hello.php` will output the word `hello` then exit, and it will do so on every page, every post, every RSS feed, every admin page, etc.

Now I wouldn't recommend doing this, as it means your site will be completely unusable until you delete the file. The `mu-plugins` folder is not a place to build your site, add features, or create content.

Basically, I don't think `mu-plugins` is what you think it is

#### What is `mu-plugins`?

This is a folder you can put PHP files in. WordPress will load those PHP files and run them before it runs the plugins and theme.

Important notes:

- They always run, on every request, wether you want them or don't
- They run earlier than plugins and themes
- These aren't plugins, it's just the name of the folder
- Plugin folders won't work, it's just single files ( you'd need to implement that yourself )
- They can't be activated or deactivated, they're not plugins
- The only way to get rid of them is to move them out of the `mu-plugins` folder

As the WP Admin screen says, it's just a folder of PHP files that automatically get executed:

[image]

They have more in common with dropins.

#### What Are `mu-plugins` Useful For?

A number of things, but:

- server level stuff, e.g. I use it to load code that helps with Cron running with Cavalcade
- Network wide hotfixes, e.g. if you visit a subdomain of my site that doesn't exist in my multisite, it'll redirect you
- Network wide rules, e.g. I might want to add things that users cannot disable in their WP Admin interfaces
  , such as forcing an option on via a filter

`mu-plugins` aren't a very good place for functionality though, but they can be useful for low-level compatibility stuff and quick snippets.

#### What I Think You Actually Want

If you want to use PHP to put things on a page, or implement a page, there are lots of far better ways to do it:

- A normal plugin in the `plugins` folder
- Shortcodes! A great way to run PHP inside content, or just embed things
- Page templates, a great way to completely change the code that powers a page
- Theme templates, what you're working with might not be a page, not to worry, there'll be a template file for that, look up the template hierarchy diagram
- Javascript!
- OEmbeds, a great way to insert 3rd party content, such as youtube video players, or other things
- Blocks! Take full advantage of the new block editor and build new blocks that add new things to your pages
- The themes `functions.php` file

You have lots of options, but the `mu-plugins` is probably the very last place you should be thinking of